# boost mpi python: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost3mpi5timer14time_is_globalEv

Tags: python, boost, mpi

I inherited a large python system that uses the boost mpi for python.
So I've built boost 1.52 from source, including both the mpi and python components.

And I've built the boost mpi for python 1.38.0.1  from http://mathema.tician.de/software/boostmpi.
I realize there are newer libraries (mpi4py), but the software I inherited uses boost mpi.

When I attempt to use it I get ...

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  4 2013, 14:54:17) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import boostmpi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/projects/nrel/cid/lada.2013/pkgi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boostmpi-1.38.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/boostmpi/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from boostmpi._internal import *
ImportError: /projects/nrel/cid/lada.2013/pkgi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boostmpi-1.38.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/boostmpi/_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost3mpi5timer14time_is_globalEv

>>> from boostmpi._internal import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/projects/nrel/cid/lada.2013/pkgi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boostmpi-1.38.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/boostmpi/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from boostmpi._internal import *
ImportError: /projects/nrel/cid/lada.2013/pkgi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boostmpi-1.38.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/boostmpi/_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost3mpi5timer14time_is_globalEv
```

How can I fix this?

Testing with ldd:

```
$ ldd /projects/nrel/cid/lada.2013/pkgi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boostmpi-1.38.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/boostmpi/_internal.so  libboost_python.so.1.52.0 => /projects/nrel/cid/lada.2013/pkgi/lib/libboost_python.so.1.52.0 (0x00002b0e45542000)
    libmpi_cxx.so.0 => /apps/x86_64/mpi/openmpi/intel-11.1-f064-c064/openmpi-1.4.2_oobpr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.0 (0x00002b0e45795000)
    libmpi.so.0 => /apps/x86_64/mpi/openmpi/intel-11.1-f064-c064/openmpi-1.4.2_oobpr/lib/libmpi.so.0 (0x00002b0e459bb000)
    libopen-rte.so.0 => /apps/x86_64/mpi/openmpi/intel-11.1-f064-c064/openmpi-1.4.2_oobpr/lib/libopen-rte.so.0 (0x00002b0e45e94000)
    libopen-pal.so.0 => /apps/x86_64/mpi/openmpi/intel-11.1-f064-c064/openmpi-1.4.2_oobpr/lib/libopen-pal.so.0 (0x00002b0e46162000)
    librdmacm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/librdmacm.so.1 (0x00002b0e463ef000)
    libibverbs.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libibverbs.so.1 (0x00002b0e465f5000)
    libpsm_infinipath.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpsm_infinipath.so.1 (0x00002b0e46802000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1 (0x00002b0e46a4c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b0e46c6a000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00002b0e46e6e000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b0e47086000)
    libmpi_f77.so.0 => /apps/x86_64/mpi/openmpi/intel-11.1-f064-c064/openmpi-1.4.2_oobpr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.0 (0x00002b0e4728a000)
    libimf.so => /projects/global/x86_64/compilers/intel/intel-11.1-cproc-064/lib/intel64/libimf.so (0x00002b0e474cb000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b0e4785d000)
    libsvml.so => /projects/global/x86_64/compilers/intel/intel-11.1-cproc-064/lib/intel64/libsvml.so (0x00002b0e47ae1000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b0e47cf7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b0e47ff7000)
    libintlc.so.5 => /projects/global/x86_64/compilers/intel/intel-11.1-cproc-064/lib/intel64/libintlc.so.5 (0x00002b0e48206000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b0e48343000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b0e4855e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002b0e488b7000)
    libinfinipath.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libinfinipath.so.4 (0x00002b0e48ac0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b0e45021000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres your problem

```
boostmpi-1.38.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/boostmpi/_internal.so  libboost_python.so.1.52.0 => /projects/nrel/cid/lada.2013/pkgi/lib/libboost_python.so.1.52.0
```

boostmpi-1.38.0

libboost_python.1.52.0

You have to fix your path its picking up two different versions of boost,

Comment: Actually boost_mpi_python is a separate product from boost.  Boost [http://www.boost.org] is 1.52.0.  The add-on boost_mpi-Python  [http://mathema.tician.de/software/boostmpi] is 1.38.0.1.

Comment: Yes but you are mistaken, you have to compile Boost_mpi-python separate from the regular boost packages, It comes standard on any boost download from source just not compiled, so you have two conflicting versions of BOOST on your system, the link above from your professor is outdated, It is not a separate product [http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/mpi/python.html#mpi.python_quickstart]

Answer (score 1):

You've built your libs incorrectly. Your boostmpi/_internal.so either is not linked to some boost-mpi lib or expects a different version from what you have. You can use

```
ldd /projects/nrel/cid/lada.2013/pkgi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boostmpi-1.38.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/boostmpi/_internal.so
```

to check what library is being loaded, if at all.

Comment: I tried ldd and all 24 entries were resolved.  I checked each with ls and they all exist.  Details are above.

Comment: So your lib is not linked to libboost-mpi but uses symbols from it.